# Multiple or operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple console based game in node.JS but have fell short at the first hurdle. Entering any characters always returns the invalidMove variable. What am i doing wrong here ?

```
const invalidMove = 'This is not a valid input, please try again';

let move = prompt('use W/A/S/D to move in any direction!  '); //get user input
  if((move !== 'W') || (move !== 'A') || (move !== 'S') || (move !== 'D')) {
        console.log(invalidMove);
  }
```

Comment: You probably mean `&&`, because all of them need to be false for it to be an invalid move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `&&` in this case to check if *none* of those keys were pressed.

```js
const invalidMove = 'This is not a valid input, please try again';

let move = prompt('use W/A/S/D to move in any direction!'); //get user input

move = move.toUpperCase();

if ((move !== 'W') && (move !== 'A') && (move !== 'S') && (move !== 'D')) {
  console.log(invalidMove);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the speedy response. Got myself confused with the operators !

Answer (score 0):

This will never be false, unless until you can find a way to enter all the 4 buttons, 'A', 'S', 'W' & 'D' at once. Maybe you can try:

```
if(!['A', 'S', 'W','D'].includes(move.toLocaleUpperCase())) {
        console.log(invalidMove);
  }
```

Comment: I have not yet studied the includes method, but this is an interesting way to shorten the code, thankyou !